# Call a function from Database to make a user defined function

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, call

Hi I'm working on a project that allows a user to add his/her own functions to the site, my problem is how can I make those functions work to elaborate further here's an image.

All the functions that are made in this page are stored in a Database

[image]

Once the user toggles the function that he/she made they should work(this the current problem)

[image]

My idea is to put a function in a database, In a way that it can be called so I/user can modify it for the adding function purposes. How can I accomplish this?any suggestion or comment is highly appreciated

Comment: Can you wrap the function into <script> tag and insert it to the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a script tag and append it to the body.

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.text = "alert('your function here')";
$("body").append( script );
```

Comment: using jquery is not needed, op is not using it in his code.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut- I appreciate both of your answers, and I think both of your ideas might do the trick, if you could elaborate it futher I would gladly appreciate it thank you

Comment: @kasper Taeymans- I appreciate both of your answers, and I think both of your ideas might do the trick, if you could elaborate it futher I would gladly appreciate it thank you

Comment: what part needs elaboration? you didn't provide any of your code.

Answer (score 1):

you can execute strings with eval() command:

```
eval("<?php echo $row['jscode']; ?>");
```

but if you use ajax to get the function and use this:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
var code = 'function lowercase() {}'; //get this from db
try {
  s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
  document.body.appendChild(s);
} catch (e) {
  s.text = code;
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

you'll ensure that the function is added and ready to execute.

Comment: if you think this comment is not useful/wrong please comment so i can improve.